# Run Event after button get pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, events, loops, button

I have a `code` which reads information from a file and displays them to the user.... now i want to `STOP` my `code` after displaying the information to the the user and `WAIT` for the `buttonpress` which starts my `event`, because the button clears the `textbox` and returns some information the the user / admin ...

But i don't have any idea how to break my code from running and wait for the `button` to get pressed...

Thx a lot

```
StringBuilder strbuildsection = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder strbuildbetreff = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder strbuildinhalt = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder strbuilduser = new StringBuilder(System.Environment.UserName);
        StringBuilder strbuildusercheck = new StringBuilder();


        foreach (string Ccat in this.ini.IniGetCategories())
        {
            string readval = ini.IniReadValue(Ccat, "Read");
            string usercheckvar = (this.ini.IniReadValue(Ccat, "SpecifyUser"));
            string user = System.Environment.UserName;

            if (readval == "0")
            {
                if (usercheckvar == user || usercheckvar.Equals("All"))
                {
                    strbuildsection.Append(Ccat + Environment.NewLine);
                    foreach (string cat in this.ini.IniGetKeys(Ccat))
                    {
                        strbuildinhalt.Clear();
                        strbuildusercheck.Clear();
                        strbuildbetreff.Clear();

                        strbuildbetreff.Append(this.ini.IniReadValue(Ccat, "Betreff") + Environment.NewLine);
                        strbuildinhalt.Append(this.ini.IniReadValue(Ccat, "Inhalt") + Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                    textBox1.AppendText(strbuildsection.ToString() + strbuildbetreff.ToString() + strbuildinhalt.ToString() + strbuildusercheck.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                        strbuildsection.Clear();
                // HERE  I want to stop my process and wait until the User
                // press the button and start my event
                // but i don't know how to do this
                // After this the loop continue and so on
            }

private void BT_Bestaetigung_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CODE
}
```

So i want to start my ´Event´ if the `button` get pressed and if not, the code should wait for this

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show your struggling before you ask.

Comment: What should i do ? My english isnt so good ...  @ToanVo

Comment: English is not a problem. Show us where you have problem and your current code.

Comment: Can you shwo us some code?

Comment: @brothers28 I add some Code to my Question ...

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I add some Code to my Question

Comment: whats about the button pressed event?

Comment: From your current code, I don't see the actual loop which you want to resume. Is there another loop around your posted code?

Comment: If I got you correctly, you would like to iterate through a list of Categories, show some extract of them to the user (allow him to look, maybe edit and most importabtly confirm them) one after the other - is that right?

Comment: Yeah ... he get the Information from an INI, get the information at the Textbox, and only can read the Information, confirm the Information wile pressing the Button (change some values so he dont get the information again) and after this, the loop check if there are other messages... @Marwie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems you placed the code in the form which you showed to the user and this blocks you from stopping to wait for the user to respond because you are still inside your loop.

The solution is to use a separate modal dialog:

Create a separate `Form` which you construct inside your loop and show it to the user when necessary - wait for the form to be closed - work on the results and repeat until done.

Inside this new form you place your controls and buttons that the user needs to interact with and fill them before you show it to him.

```
        frmConfirmationDialog myConfirmationDialog = new frmConfirmationDialog()

        //Fill in information to show to the user
        myConfirmationDialog.textBox1.AppendText(strbuildsection.ToString() + strbuildbetreff.ToString() + strbuildinhalt.ToString() + strbuildusercheck.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

        //Open Form modally (this will stop your loop until the dialog is closed)
        DialogResult myResult = myConfirmationDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (myResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Do Stuff here
        }
        else //catch further type of results here (you could also work with a switch statement
        {
            //Do Stuff here
        }
```

BTW to get a DialogResult when closing the form set the `DialogResult` Property of the Confirm or Cancel Buttons to the values you like. This will cause the modal form to be automatically closed with the DialogResult of the button. If you need to catch stuff before closing the form you can either implement an EventHandler for `FormClosing` or handle the `Click` event of the buttons.

Comment: Do you have a Code example?

Comment: @Maewie:  I add a timer to read the file every (time) but now the new Dialog get displayed really often and stopping the timer and start at the end dont work ...

Comment: Please describe your problem in a new question in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
            bool stop = false;
            Thread thread = null;

            btnShow.Click += (source, e) =>
            {
                stop = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Show something");
            };

            btnClose.Click += (source, e) =>
            {
                stop = false;
            };

            if (thread == null)
            {
                thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true) // your working loop
                    {
                        while (stop)
                        {}

                        // action of your loop 
                        Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next());

                    }
                });
                thread.Start();
           }
```

Comment: btn1 is the name of your button. try it.

Comment: this wouldn't actually stop the loop from running.

Comment: thats right, so implement a while(textboxshown) inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think it this way: you have a *continous* operation and you are waiting for the user interaction.

In winforms application, where you can not perform continous operation in UI thread (because your window required constantly receive messages from os, i.e. user input or repaint requrests and have to react to them, or you will have *laggy* or even *frozen* UI), typical solution is:

- split operation into sub-operations (which are short and doesn't cause UI lags);
- put operation into a thread.

So, basicaly, go this way (there is a pattern to avoid using switch with delegating steps, but for simplicity we show classical way):

```
_timer = new Timer();
_timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
...
// in timer tick
switch(_operation)
{
    case operation1:
        _operation = nextoperation; // _operation++
        ...
        break;
    case operation2:
        // do nothing, wait for button press
        if(_buttonPressed)
            _operation = nextoperation;
        break;
    case operation3:
        // continue after button press
        ..
    ...
}
```

or this way

```
_thread = new Thread(...)
thread.Start();
...
// in thread
// start operation
...
// wait for button press
while(_buttonPressed)
    Thread.Sleep(0);
// continue operation
...
```

in both cases

```
// in button click event
_buttonPressed = true;
```